# Altering a list using append during a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

**Caveat: this is a straight up question for code-golfing, so I know what I'm asking is bad practise in production**

I'm trying to alter an array during a list comprehension, but for some reason it is hanging and I don't know why or how to fix this.

I'm dealing with a list of lists of indeterminite depth and need to condense them to a flat list - [for those curious its this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15783/check-wheter-there-are-more-even-then-odd-numbers-on-any-given-nested-list). But at this stage, lets just say I need a flat list of all the elements in the list, and 0 if it is a list.

The normal method is to iterate through the list and if its a list add it to the end, like so:

```
for o in x:
 if type(o)==type([]):x+=o
 else:i+=o
print i
```

I'm trying to shorten this using list comprehension, like so.

```
print sum([
 [o,x.append(o) or 0][type(o)==type([])]
 for o in x
]))
```

Now, I know `List.append` returns None, so to ensure that I get a numeric value, lazy evaluation says I can do `x.append(o) or 0`, and since `None` is "falsy" it will evaulate the second part and the value is `0`.

But it doesn't. If I put `x.append()` into the list comprehension over `x`, it doesn't break or error, or return an iteration error, it just freezes. **Why does `append` freeze during the list comprehension, but the `for` loop above works fine?**

**edit: To keep this question from being deleted**, I'm not looking for golfing tips (they are very educational though), I was looking for an answer as to why the code wasn't working as I had written it.

Comment: Off-topic for this question, but for the original problem: Wouldn't it be simpler to flatten the nested iterable into an iterator (which you can do in a 2-line function in 3.3+, a 3-line function without, if you can't use third-party modules like `more-itertools`), then just write the trivial code over that iterator?

Comment: @abarnert `from itertools import*` is 22 characters long, then you need to call the actual method. Which is quite a price to pay just for a library.

Comment: `sum(map(lambda x:x%2-.5, flatten(a)))` is only 37 characters. 22+1+37=60, which certainly beats the 73 that's there now.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, but you need to get `input()` which is another 7 and define flatten as per the receipes as it isn't a method in `itertools`. This is probably stretching the appropriate use of the comments section, but feel free to submit an alternate solution at Golf.SE if you can beat me :)

Comment: Yes, but it is in `more-itertools`, which is why I said "third-party modules like `more-itertools` in my original comment. (I believe it's called `collapse` rather than `flatten`, which unfortunately adds 1 character…)

Comment: @abarnert Ah in that case its most probably not legal.

Comment: Yeah, then you'd need something like `def f(x):` `try: yield from map(f, x)` `except: yield x`, which is longer, and requires Python 3.3+.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42905/discussion-between-lego-stormtroopr-and-abarnert)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`or` may be lazy, but list definitions aren't.  For each `o` in `x`, when the `[o,x.append(o) or 0][type(o)==type([])]` monstrosity is evaluated, Python has to evaluate `[o,x.append(o) or 0]`, which means evaluating `x.append(o) or 0`, which means that `o` will be appended to `x` regardless of whether it's a list.  Thus, you end up with every element of `x` appended to `x`, and then they get appended again and again and again and `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: I must have not been waiting long enough to see the error. Back to the drawing board I guess :(

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: If you're on 64-bit Python, on a platform that expands swap as needed (as OS X and Windows both do by default), the error may not hit until after hours of swap thrashing…

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
y = [element for element in x if type(element) != list or x.extend(element)]
```

(note that `extend` will flatten, while `append` will only add the nested list back to the end, unflattened).

Comment: Why not just do `type(element) != list`?  `list` *is* the type of `[]`.

Comment: Ahem, right! I was altering @Lego's code and got carried with the wind :) Thanks! Corrected!

Comment: Brilliant golfing, but it doesn't really answer the question. Though, I couldn't in good consciousness submit this as my own solution at to the challenge and suggest you do instead.

Comment: Not ruining at all :)